# LinkedList delete test fail

Tags: java, list, hyperlink

```
public void delete(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > count-1) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    Node<X> current = head;
    if (index == 0) {
        current = current.getLink();
        count--;
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < index-1; i++) {
        current = current.getLink();
    }

    current.setLink(current.getLink().getLink());
    count--;

}
```

.

```
@Test
public void testDeleteSeveral()
{
    LList<String> b = new LList<String>();
    b.add("hello");
    b.add("bye");
    b.add("adios");
    b.add("ciao");
    b.add("see ya");
    b.delete(0);
    assertEquals(4, b.size());
    assertEquals("ciao", b.get(0));
    assertEquals("adios", b.get(1));
    assertEquals("bye", b.get(2));
    assertEquals("hello", b.get(3));
```

.

```
public void add(X v)
{
    Node<X> a = new Node<X>();
    a.setValue(v);
    a.setLink(head);
    head = a;
    count++;
}
```

Where it says  `assertEquals("ciao", b.get(0));`, I put that it should be "ciao" since it delete the first node, but the error shows up as it was expecting "see ya", when I thought "see ya" was deleted since i did `delete(0);` am I missing something?

EDIT: I added the add method

Comment: Are you sure that your LList is ordered?

Comment: Your add method is not adding to the tail. It is actually inserting at the head. Not sure if this is intentional but when I saw "add()", I thought it would add to the tail which is the order in which the elements were inserted. So hello->bye->adios->ciao->see ya. But your implementation is reversed. see ya->ciao->adios->bye->hello

Comment: yes that was intentional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete method is incorrect.  Here's a corrected version, with explanation for what you did wrong.

```
    if (index == 0)
    {
        //we're deleting the head here. You need to reassign head variable.
        //current = current.getLink(); <-- no. this doesn't change the structure.
        head = head.getLink();//here we set head to head's next. Now structure is changed.
        count--;
        return;
    }
```

Also, your add method is a bit odd.  It's appending items to the front of your queue.  Maybe that's what you meant to do, but just be aware as its written, items will be in reverse order from what you added.  So...

```
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
```

Will actually contain items in order `[3, 2, 1]` not `[1, 2, 3]`.

I'll assume you didn't want this, and write you a new add method.

```
public void add(X v)
{
    Node<X> a = new Node<X>();
    a.setValue(v);
    if(head==null)
        head = a;
    else
    {
        Node<X> tail = getTail();
        tail.setLink(a);
    }
    count++;
}
private Node<X> getTail(){
    if(head==null)
        return null;
    Node<X> current = head;
    while(current.getLink()!=null)
        current = current.getLink();
    return current;
}
```

This will add items in order to your list.  A consequence, however is that adding an item is O(n) now.  This is unavoidable in a single-linked list.

Edit:

Rewrote your routine.  I'm bored, forgive me.

```
public void delete(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > count-1) {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    if (index == 0) {
        head = head.getLink();
    }else{
        Node<X> beforeDeletedNode = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index-1; i++) {
            beforeDeletedNode = beforeDeletedNode.getLink();
        }
        Node<X> toDelete = beforeDeletedNode.getLink();
        beforeDeletedNode.setLink(toDelete.getLink());
    }
    count--;

}
```

Comment: thank you, that makes sense, you were first so ill give you check

Comment: Thanks, please read the part about your add routine. It is reversed as you've posted.

Comment: yes having it in reverse was the whole point. good catch though

Comment: Oh, sorry, haha.  I posted code to add in order if you ever need it.  Good luck @user3427042

Answer (score 1):

Your delete method has a problem here.

```
if (index == 0)
{
    current = current.getLink();
    count--;
    return;
}
```

It is not actually deleting because the "head" is still refering to the same node. Try

```
if (index == 0)
{
    head = current.getLink();
    count--;
    return;
}
```

Comment: You're welcomed. But your problem doesn't end there. I'm a bit suspicious about the next for() loop because it doesn't work for when index = 1. The for() loop is skipped.

Comment: @anonymous The `for` loop should be skipped in that case.  It got me for a second too.  Just an odd way to write the routine imho.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison I suspect he'll get NullPointerException when removing the LAST node.

Comment: @anonymous he won't.  His routine gets the node preceding the last node if there are more than 1 nodes. This means the next link will never be null when removing the last node in the series, as you'll actually be manipulating the second to last node. I rewrote the routine in my answer. Its a little more readable for me personally (go figure, I wrote it.)

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Yep, you are correct. Your code is definitely more readable.